# nfcpy retrieves the URL from a NFC tag. But how do I open the link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, nfc

## What I want:

I want my Raspberry Pi to act as a NFC-reader that can trigger the URL record from a NFC tag.

My setup is a Raspberry Pi with a [PN532 NFC HAT](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/PN532_NFC_HAT) and [nfcpy](https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy). I am using the example [tagtool.py](https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy/tree/master/examples) and right now I am able to scan the NFC-tag and then show the URL (+ some extra data)

But I want the system to run the URL which triggers a webhook on IFTTT (which then triggers a playlist on Spotify...)

## What I have done so far:

I have used setup.py to install nfcpy and experimented a bit with the commands. But when I run the command

```
python3 tagtool.py --device tty:S0:pn532 -d nfc.ndef.UriRecord -l
```

It first returns this

```
[main] enable debug output for 'nfc.ndef.UriRecord'
[nfc.clf] searching for reader on path tty:S0:pn532
[nfc.clf] using PN532v1.6 at /dev/ttyS0
** waiting for a tag **
```

and then when I scan one of my NFC tags - which have a URL in URI Record - with the reader I get this message.

```
Type2Tag 'NXP NTAG213' ID=04EA530A3E4D80
NDEF Capabilities:
  readable  = yes
  writeable = yes
  capacity  = 137 byte
  message   = 67 byte
NDEF Message:
record 1
  type = 'urn:nfc:wkt:U'
  name = ''
  data = b'\x04maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Playlist_022/with/key/bVTin_XXEEEDDDDEEEEEE'
[main] *** RESTART ***
[nfc.clf] searching for reader on path tty:S0:pn532
[nfc.clf] using PN532v1.6 at /dev/ttyS0
** waiting for a tag **
```

As you can see the URL is right there under data (+b\x04 but without https:\ but I guess thats quite easy to change). So basically I just need to trigger it.

I read somewhere that I could use curlify so I have used the command 'pip3 install curlify' and made some changes to tagtool.py.

The original tagtool.py (which I believe is the most important part for what I am trying to do) looks like this

```
        if tag.ndef:
            print("NDEF Capabilities:")
            print("  readable  = %s" % ("no", "yes")[tag.ndef.is_readable])
            print("  writeable = %s" % ("no", "yes")[tag.ndef.is_writeable])
            print("  capacity  = %d byte" % tag.ndef.capacity)
            print("  message   = %d byte" % tag.ndef.length)
            if tag.ndef.length > 0:
                print("NDEF Message:")
                for i, record in enumerate(tag.ndef.records):
                    print("record", i + 1)
                    print("  type =", repr(record.type))
                    print("  name =", repr(record.name))
                    print("  data =", repr(record.data))
```

In the new tagtool2.py I have added this to the start of the document

```
import curlify
import requests
```

And then I have added this line

```
            response = requests.get("https://repr(record.data)")
            print(curlify.to_curl(response.request))
```

Which means it looks like this. And this is probably wrong in several ways:

```
        if tag.ndef:
            print("NDEF Capabilities:")
            print("  readable  = %s" % ("no", "yes")[tag.ndef.is_readable])
            print("  writeable = %s" % ("no", "yes")[tag.ndef.is_writeable])
            print("  capacity  = %d byte" % tag.ndef.capacity)
            print("  message   = %d byte" % tag.ndef.length)
            if tag.ndef.length > 0:
                print("NDEF Message:")
                for i, record in enumerate(tag.ndef.records):
                    print("record", i + 1)
                    print("  type =", repr(record.type))
                    print("  name =", repr(record.name))
                    print("  data =", repr(record.data))
                    response = requests.get("https://repr(record.data)")
                    print(curlify.to_curl(response.request))
```

Because when I try to trigger the URL with a NFC tag I get this message:

```
Type2Tag 'NXP NTAG213' ID=04EA530A3E4D80
NDEF Message:
record 1
  type = 'urn:nfc:wkt:U'
  name = ''
  data = b'\x04maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Metal1/with/key/bVTin_XXEEEDDDDEEEEEE'
[urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repr(record.data):443
[nfc.clf] HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repr(record.data)', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb579a650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? And if curlify is the right way to go?

Comment: Please see the documentation at https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/get-started.html#read-and-write-tags around the 4th and 5th code sample. Basically you just need to read the tag.ndef.records list to get the appropriately decoded URI.

Comment: I have spend a lot of time on that page and still managed to overlook these two fine examples. Well, a lot of time wasted on that accound, but hopefully I have learned something I wouldnt have learned otherwise. I will change my answer

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that the data stored in the NDEF message is encoded, you cannot just open a connection using the raw data you have to decode it first using the correct type. (as the encoded value has a Hex number in it)

It is also encoded in `utf-8` so Python treats it as `bytes` not as a `string` type object.

So the type says it is a `URI` record type as you used 'nfc.ndef.UriRecord' (Don't know why call it urn instead)

So the Hex number `\x04` means `https://`

Unfortunately I don't think anybody has written a decoder method for the NFC Uri specification only encoders.
Here is a link full spec for the [NDEF URI record type](https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_URI_1.0.pdf)

once you have replaced the Hex character in the data with the correct decoded value you will get the URL `https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Metal1/with/key/bVTin_XXEEEDDDDEEEEEE`

a simple example (where `a` stores the value instead of `record.data`)

```python
import re

a = b'\x04maker.ifttt.com/trigger/Metal1/with/key/bVTin_XXEEEDDDDEEEEEE'
a_text = a.decode('utf-8')

x = re.sub('\x04', 'https://', a_text)

print(x)

requests.get(x)
```

Then you can use `requests.get()` on the decoded value

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the simple but good solution for my needs.

```
        if tag.ndef:

            if tag.ndef.length > 0:
                #print("NDEF Message:")
                for i, record in enumerate(tag.ndef.records):
                    print(record.uri)                                       
                    response = requests.get(record.uri)
                    print(curlify.to_curl(response.request))
```

I started out with a way more complicated solution. I am keeping it here if anybody runs into similar problems.

Since the first take, I have cleaned out some of the print() lines as well, and I know I can clean out some more lines, but I am keeping them here to make it easier to see whats happening.

Its especially worth noticing the y variable. I was left with an almost perfect URL, but I kept getting errors because of an extra ' at the end of the URL.

```
        if tag.ndef:

            if tag.ndef.length > 0:
                for i, record in enumerate(tag.ndef.records):
                    print(repr(record.data))
                    print(str(record.data))
                    org_string = str(record.data)
                    mod_string = org_string[6:]
                    y = mod_string.rstrip(mod_string[-1])                    
                    w = "https://"
                    print(mod_string)
                    print(y)
                    print(w)
                    response = requests.get(w + y)
                    print(curlify.to_curl(response.request))
```

The code can be improved, but it works and it gives me this message and - more important - it triggers the URL on the NFC tag (I have scrambled the IFTTT webhook).

```
Type2Tag 'NXP NTAG215' ID=04722801E14103
b'\x04maker.ifttt.com/trigger/python_test/with/key/bEDoi_gUT5x5uDsdsaR3Ao'
b'\x04maker.ifttt.com/trigger/python_test/with/key/bEDoi_gUT5x5uDsdsaR3Aoo'
maker.ifttt.com/trigger/python_test/with/key/bEDoi_gUT5x5uDsdsaR3Ao'
maker.ifttt.com/trigger/python_test/with/key/bEDoi_gUT5x5uDsdsaR3Ao
https://
[urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): maker.ifttt.com:443
[urllib3.connectionpool] https://maker.ifttt.com:443 "GET maker.ifttt.com/trigger/python_test/with/key/bEDoi_gUT5x5uDsdsaR3Ao HTTP/1.1" 200 69
curl -X GET -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/python_test/with/key/bEDoi_gUT5x5uDsdsaR3Ao
[main] *** RESTART ***
[nfc.clf] searching for reader on path tty:S0:pn532
[nfc.clf] using PN532v1.6 at /dev/ttyS0
** waiting for a tag **
```